# MS Word 2007: WordBasic.SelectSimilarFormatting produces an error

Tags: vba, ms-word

My macro contains

```
WordBasic.SelectSimilarFormatting
```

this line worked for years, and even in Word 2007, but now it started to produce following error:

```
Run-time error '509':
This command is not available.
```

I have two questions:

- What could happen that a line which always worked stopped working suddenly?
- How to rewrite this line in VBA and not use WordBasic ?

Comment: This error number is giving different description to that you mentioned- `Application-defined of object-definded error`. It doesn't mean that you are wrong, there could be different context of calling that error number. Did you try it with new document after restart of Word? Did it happen after a lots of operation made in word? please check if there isn't a copy of `SelectSimilarFormatting` nowhere in any open document. Answering your last question- it is feasible but difficult, you would need to check formatting parameters and than search them (`.Range.Find`) throughout the whole document...

Comment: Have you been working on the code in the template recently? This is a long shot, but I have found that, very occasionally, perfectly fine code will stop working and need to be 'recompiled'; basically, you have to put a space after the line, or hit enter or something and then resave the template. This happens more frequently with Enum declarations than anything else, but it's kind of mysterious so it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to turn an option `Keep track of formatting` on. Without it the menu option `Select Text with Similar Formatting` and the `WordBasic.SelectSimilarFormatting` macro command do not work.